# Why am i getting this error for my insert statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

```
insert into filiaal (filiaalnummer, plaats, adres)
values (35, "Utrecht", "Stationsplein")
```

ERROR:  column "Utrecht" does not exist
LINE 2: values (35, utrecht, "Stationsplein")

Why does it say column Utrecht doesn't exist? I know it doesn't, i'm trying to enter "Utrecht" as a value in the plaats column of the filiaal table.

Comment: It's because of the routes of quotes you use.

Comment: It's because of the routes of quotes you use.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS